# podspec warning: no rule to process file for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, xcode

My Podspec like this:

s.resource = 'JOBaseSDK/Resources/**/*.{png,txt}'

I'll get warning when pod spec lint in terminal

- NOTE  |  warning: no rule to process file 'JOProjectBaseSDK/JOBaseSDK/Resources/111.txt' of type text for architecture i386
- NOTE  |  warning: no rule to process file 'JOProjectBaseSDK/JOBaseSDK/Resources/111.txt' of type text for architecture x86_64

Anyone can help me fix it? thanks!

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Define for resource files seems OK. Can you check if files with .txt extensions are not added also to sources in podspec?

It seems that  there is an attempt to compile .txt file. If txt file is present in "compile sources" build phase, it will generate this kind of warning.